# Are there similar tools to Clone Detective for other languages/IDEs?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic

I just saw [Clone Detective](http://www.codeplex.com/CloneDetectiveVS) linked on YCombinator news, and the idea heavily appeals to me. It seems like it would be useful for many languages, not just C#, but I haven't seen anything similar elsewhere.

Edit: For those who don't want to follow the link, Clone Detective scans the codebase for duplicate code that may warrant refactoring to minimize duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has a few - some of the most popular static analysis tools have this built in along with many other useful rules.

Ones I have used, in the (purely subjective) order that I was happiest with:

- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) - comes with [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html) - their copy and paste detector
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html) - specific [rules](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_duplicates.html) to look for duplicate code
- [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) - the daddy of all Java static analysis tools.  Includes duplicate code detection, along with just about anything else that you can think of, but quite resource intensive

There are some [nice](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) [IDE](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html) [plugins](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html) for all of these and many other reporting tools (for example, you can see results on a [Hudson continuos build server](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/Violations), or your project's [Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/))

Answer (score 2):

The [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) IDE (Java, Scala, Ruby,...) has a [Locate Duplicate...](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_duplicate.html) tool. Usefull indeed !